# Pause video when image reference is not tracked

Tags: arkit, realitykit

I made this script in RealityKit & SwiftUI that when a reference image is detected it overlays a video with the same filename on top of it.

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    var parent: ARViewContainer
    var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()
    
    init(parent: ARViewContainer) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        guard let validAnchor = anchors[0] as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: validAnchor)
        anchor.addChild(createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(validAnchor.referenceImage))
        parent.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        
        
    }
    
    func createdVideoPlayerNodeFor(_ target: ARReferenceImage) -> ModelEntity {
        var videoPlane = ModelEntity()
        //var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()
        if let targetName = target.name,
           let validURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: targetName, withExtension: "mp4") {
            videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: validURL)
            videoPlayer.play()
        }
        let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
        videoPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: Float(target.physicalSize.width), depth: Float(target.physicalSize.height)), materials: [videoMaterial])
        print (target.name as Any)
        return videoPlane
    }
}
```

It works as intended, but I would like to pause the video when the reference image is not tracked (without pausing other videos that might be in the view at the same time). I tried experimenting with this, but it doesn't work - it either pauses all videos or doesn't work at all.

```
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let validAnchor = anchors[0] as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        
        if validAnchor.isTracked {
            videoPlayer.play()
            print("Played")
        } else {
            videoPlayer.pause()
            print("Paused")
        }
    }
```

How do I target only the video that stops being tracked, please?